# jquery get width of previous image

Tags: jquery

So i cant get the jquery correct for this one, whatever i try it returns the wrong width.
I wish to make the image within the "img-shadow" div the same size as the image right before it. Notice this will repeat several times on the page.

```
<p>
  <img src="" alt="">
  <span class="img-shadow">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </span>
</p>
```

I hope you don't shake your heads too much on at me on this one, it seems super simple, but .prev .find .closest hasn't worked for me.

Thanks!

Solution added:

Jquery

```
$(".img-shadow").each(function(){
    $(this).children("img").width( $(this).parent().find('img').width() );
});
```

Comment: Another thought on that: a `<div>` within a `<p>` is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but I didn't test it:

```
$('.img-shadow').width( $('.img-shadow').parent().find('img').width() );
```

Comment: It didn't work, can it have something to do with img not being prev of .img-shadow because they are not of the same element type?

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer. But seems to much effort for the task.

Comment: hehe yeah i felt the same way, i tried this but unfortunately same result

Comment: wait, this might be right, but all images are getting the first img width, will investigate further

Comment: Yes got it working, updated the answer. Thanks for your help insertusernamehere!